# Use complex type object In another component in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm new to angular 2 and I'm implementing user sign-In page.If entered email already exist Web API returns user data object. Currently i'm writing that object in console. But I need that object use inside userExist.component.ts.

**These 'auth.component.ts' and 'userExist.component.ts' are independent controllers**

auth.component .ts

```js
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {

 ( ......)
   
 userRegister() {
   
   ( ......)
    
   this.userService.loginRegisterUser(this.userRegisterModel)
      .subscribe(
      data =>{ 
        console.log(data); // working!!   
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/user-exist');   
      },     
      err => {
        alert(err);
        this.errors = err;
        this.isRegistering = false;
      }
      );
   }
}
```

userExist.component.ts

```js
export class UserExistComponent implements OnInit {

  userRegisterModel:LoggedUserRegister = new LoggedUserRegister ();

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private userService: UserService,  private fb: FormBuilder,) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this. userRegisterModel = // I need assign object from auth.component.ts
  }
}
```

anyone can tell me how should I read object of auth.component.ts inside userExist.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one of the message passing mechanism using shared service/event emitter. In this case since your components are independent, use a **`shared service.`**

**EXAMPLE**

```
@Injectable()
export class sharedService {
 userRegisterModel:LoggedUserRegister ;
 constructor() {
}
 Initialize() {

}

 saveUser(input:any) {
    this.userRegisterModel = input;
 }

 getUser(){
    return this.userRegisterModel;
 }
}
```

then inside the **`AuthComponent`**

```
data =>{ 
        this.sharedService.saveUser(data);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/user-exist');   
}
```

again if you want the detail in other component use **`getUser`** method

Comment: Yes it worked. It's very easy method to use.this will very helpful to beginners like me :) Thank you #Sajeetharan

Comment: @isankathalagala any time :)